# How to find and set the user of R in linux?

Tags: r

I yum install R recently.When I `cat/passwd`, I can find the user like apache,mysql,but there's no a user named R.
There must be a user run R,who is it?
For the safety, how to set the right permission to R user,usergroup?

Comment: There usually isn't a user named R. If you are starting R from the command line, then it is simply run by the user that started it.